# Will any cordova (webview) app for children under 13 be rejected by the play store? Any way around it?

Tags: cordova, google-play

I'm making an educational app for children under 13 using cordova. It was rejected from the Play Store for the following reason:

> During review, we found that your app violates the Families Policy
> Requirements. We don't allow apps whose primary purpose is to provide
> a webview of a website, regardless of ownership, or to aggregate
> content that does not belong to the developer.
>
> For example, we have detected that your app generates a webview of a
> website without additional functionality.

My app doesn't actually access a website, it just uses cordova. Does this mean any app for children that uses cordova will be rejected because cordova is generating a webview? I'm new to programming, so may be misunderstanding what webview means. Is there any way around this?